# .NET: What is making my Form resize on Show()

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Before showing a form my code adjusts its size, but after calling its Show() method it has a size that is neither the one it's initialized to in ...Designer.vb nor the one I just set it to.

I set a breakpoint in its Resize() handler, and the chain of calls from Show() to Resize() looks like this:

```
MyApp.exe!MyApp.SearchListForm.frmSearchList_Resize(Object eventSender, System.EventArgs eventArgs) Line 2256   Basic
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnResize(System.EventArgs e) + 0xbb bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnResize(System.EventArgs e) + 0xd bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnSizeChanged(System.EventArgs e) + 0x29 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height, int clientWidth, int clientHeight) + 0x9c bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.UpdateBounds() + 0xd1 bytes   
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmCreate(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x29 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x2e7 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x2a bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x10 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmCreate(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0xe bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x193 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x10 bytes    
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(ref System.Windows.Forms.Message m) + 0x31 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(System.IntPtr hWnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) + 0x57 bytes 
[Native to Managed Transition]  
[Managed to Native Transition]  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(int dwExStyle, string lpszClassName, string lpszWindowName, int style, int x, int y, int width, int height, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hWndParent, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hMenu, System.Runtime.InteropServices.HandleRef hInst, object pvParam) + 0x3c bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.CreateHandle(System.Windows.Forms.CreateParams cp) + 0x225 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateHandle() + 0x125 bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.CreateHandle() + 0x9f bytes  
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Handle.get() + 0x45 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Form.SetVisibleCore(bool value) + 0x160 bytes 
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Show() + 0x10 bytes
```

I'm assuming there's some component with a Location and Size that force the Form to shape itself to their needs, but I can't really tell from the stack trace and I don't know how to find out what the cause is.

Any suggestions?

TIA

Comment: Does your form has the autosize property set to true ?

Comment: AutoSize and AutoScale are both False

Comment: Was there any resolution to this issue?  I am having the same problem.  AutoSize and AutoScale are both false, the window has no borders, caption, or minimize/maximize button, or menu.  Yet when  UpdateBounds() is called, UnsafeNativeMethods.GetClientRect() and UnsafeNativeMethods.GetWindowRect() return sizes that are too big and not defined anywhere in the code or resource file.

Answer (score 0):

Your AutoScaleMode is set to the default value of `Font` and you assigned a font bigger (or smaller) than the Windows default.

Comment: Or more commonly: the video adapter has a different DPI setting.

Comment: AutoSize and AutoScale are both False, but AutoScaleMode is Inherit.  I'm not sure what effect AutoScaleMode has, if any, when AutoScale is False.  As it happens, the shape of the form is getting both narrower and taller, with a big empty area at the bottom, so I don't really see how that can be caused by scaling to a certain font size or screen resolution.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the AutoSizeChanged, MaximumBoundsChanged and MaximumSizeChanged events are never raised.

Comment: Rule it out once and for all by setting AutoScaleMode.None

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion is that your form's initial size is small - this will cause the behavior you're seeing.  If so, give your form a MinimumSize (other than 0,0) equal to the initial size.  If you haven't provided a minimum size, it appears as though one is calculated for you when GetClientRect() and GetWindowRect() is called (during the call to UpdateBounds()), based on your environment.  For me this was 113x28.